# Multiple Date field with term attached to each instance

Tags: nodes, datetime, entities

I have a need to build a "Project" content type that has a multiple date field. This date field will be used to mark particular "Milestones" within a project. I am attempting to attache a small text field or term to each instance of the multiple date field so I can plot each date on a calendar with description.

[image]

Is there a combination of modules I can achieve this with? I was reading about [Field API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7) but was hoping there was an alternative way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a final answer, but - have you tried [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)?

Comment: Thanks you for this reference - I will have a look at post back.

Comment: Yup, I second field collection.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Field Collection is the answer with a little themeing of the node edit page -thanks for your help.